# How to solve $y''+y'\tan x+y\cos^2 x=\cos^4 x$ by substitute $z=\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve the following ODE $$y''+y'\tan x+y\cos^2 x=\cos^4 x$$ by substitute $z=\sin x.$ Thanks for reading, and hopefully answering too.

Comment: Hint: use $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}.$$

Comment: @Dear  Yves Daoust by your hint I have $\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+y=cos^2x$. I want know is it true?Thank you

Comment: @user62498 That is essentially correct. Using somewhat more careful notation, if $y(x) = f(\sin(x))$ then $f''(\sin(x)) + f(\sin(x)) = \cos^2(x)$. Now notice that $\cos^2(x) = 1-\sin^2(x) = 1-z^2$, so you have $f''(z) + f(z) = 1-z^2$.

Comment: @Dear Ian thank you, yes I have $y_h=c_1\cos z+c_2\sin z$ and $y_p=az^2+bz+c$